# SQL: Select distinct sum of column with max(column)

Tags: sql

I have a salary table like this:

```
id | person_id | start_date  | pay
1  | 1234      | 2012-01-01  | 3000
2  | 1234      | 2012-05-01  | 3500
3  | 5678      | 2012-01-01  | 5000
4  | 5678      | 2013-01-01  | 6000
5  | 9101      | 2012-09-01  | 2000
6  | 9101      | 2014-04-01  | 3000
7  | 9101      | 2011-01-01  | 1500
and so on...
```

Now I want to query the sum of the salaries of a specific month for all persons of a company.

I already have the ids of the persons who worked in the specific month in the specific company, so I can do something like WHERE person_id IN (...)

I have some problems with the salaries query though. The result for e.g. the month 2012-08 should be:

```
10000
```

which is 3500+5000+1500.

So I need to find the summed up pay value (for all persons in the IN clause) for the maximum start_date <= the specific month.

I tried various INNER JOINS but it's been a long day and I can't think straight at the moment.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the active record.  This following does this by calculating the max start date before the month in question:

```
select sum(s.pay)
from (select person_id, max(start_date) as maxstartdate
      from salary
      where person_id in ( . . . ) and
            start_date < <first day of month of interest>
      group by person_id
   ) p join
   salary s
   on s.person_id = p.person_id and
      s.maxstartdate = p.start_date
```

You need to fill in the month and list of ids.

You can also do this with ranking functions, but you don't specify which SQL engine you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for these things....

```
  select person_id,sum(pay) from salary where person_id in(...) group by person_id
```

may it will helps you.....